# On Linux (Fedora), I want to track a PARTICULAR process' I/O to find out if it's hung or is making progress

Tags: linux, fedora, io, ps, sha1

So... I'm busy trying to clean up two decades of backups an have a particular job that's trying to get a `sha1sum` on two possibly duplicate files and it appears to be hung... the operative word being "appears."

There's a LOT of other I/O going on on that disk, and there needs to be. But just this ONE job seems stuck - should have finished LONG ago. The process state is `D+` every time I look but this is what `pidstat` says:

```
Linux 6.0.12-100.fc35.x86_64 (fs2)      07/06/2023      _x86_64_        (12 CPU)

12:44:08 PM   UID       PID    %usr %system  %guest   %wait    %CPU   CPU  Command
12:44:08 PM     0    132572    0.03    0.02    0.00    0.00    0.05     8  sha1sum
```

Every once in a while, the `%CPU` creeps up a TINY amount - now at 0.05... I know how to track I/O generically but for a SPECIFIC process? That's what I'm asking about. (I don't care about the top I/O on the system, etc.)